# Gstreamer encoder for video/x-raw GRAY8 format to lower CPU usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, gstreamer, intel, video-encoding, aravis

I have been using a G-Streamer and ARAVIS project libraries to send live video feed from Genicam camera to Amazon Kinesis Video. I read the  raw video using the GREY8 format and convert it to H264 compressed data format before it goes to AWS Kinesis video. I have seen some examples on encoders such as vaapih264enc encoder for RGB format which lower the CPU usage significantly. Unfortunately I cannot seem to get it to work for GREY 8 format. Can anyone suggest any encoders I can use to lower my CPU usage which is running in high 90s. Below is the G-Streamer PIPE I have been using

**
gst-launch-1.0 -e --gst-plugin-path=/usr/local/lib/ aravissrc camera-name="Allied Vision-xxxxxxxx-xxxxx" exposure=7000 exposure-auto=0 gain=30 gain-auto=0 ! video/x-raw,format=GRAY8,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=80/1 ! videoconvert ! x264enc  bframes=0 key-int-max=45 bitrate=5500  ! h264parse ! video/x-h264,stream-format=avc,alignment=au,profile=high ! kvssink stream-name="camera_xxx" storage-size=512 access-key="aws access key" secret-key="aws secret key" aws-region="aws region"**

I'm using a Ubuntu OS on a intel motherboard.

Thank you for your time

I tried the vaapih264enc  encoder and it lowered my CPU but I expected the feed to look good but it looked like fast forwared and chopped up. Below is what I tried

**gst-launch-1.0 -e --gst-plugin-path=/usr/local/lib/ aravissrc camera-name="Allied Vision-xxxxxxxx-xxxxx" exposure=7000 exposure-auto=0 gain=30 gain-auto=0 ! video/x-raw,format=GRAY8,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=80/1 ! vaapih264enc rate-control=cbr bitrate=5000 ! h264parse ! video/x-h264,stream-format=avc,alignment=au,profile=high ! kvssink stream-name="camera_xxx" storage-size=512 access-key="aws access key" secret-key="aws secret key" aws-region="aws region"**

Comment: The 2nd pipeline is missing the `videoconvert`, so I doubt you have it running this way at all. But I have no idea what "chopped up" means. Note that the used GPU can make a big difference concerning the result.

Comment: yes you are correct. I had copied it incorrectly. I got it to work by changing the FPS to 30 and adding the videoconvert. Any value higher then that (30 FPS) it works fine at beginning but as time goes on it seems to fall behind and it starts to cut parts of video off as if the frames are getting dropped. And it also looks like its being fast forwarded. I'm hoping to see maybe if other input paraments for the encoder could help me as the client might need me to turn the FPS to 70 or 80

Comment: There are alot of input parameters for the vaapih264enc which will take me a long time to try all combinations. Any suggestions would be very helpful

Comment: Here is what I have so far that is working

 gst-launch-1.0 -e --gst-plugin-path=/usr/local/lib/ aravissrc camera-name="Allied Vision-xxxxxxxx-xxxxx" exposure=7000 exposure-auto=0 gain=30 gain-auto=0 ! video/x-raw,format=GRAY8,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! vaapih264enc rate-control=cbr bitrate=5000 ! h264parse ! video/x-h264,stream-format=avc,alignment=au,profile=high ! kvssink stream-name="camera_xxx" storage-size=512 access-key="aws access key" secret-key="aws secret key" aws-region="aws region"

Comment: 80 fps is quite demanding. Also 5mbit is quite ambitious for 1080p80. Check your GPU what it actually is specified for.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I will try to look into the machine specs to make sure. One thing I forgot to mention we have previously got it to work with 80FPS using video/x-bayer and rgb format without any issues.  But the client liked the grey 8 format a lot more so we switched it. So why would a format make a huge difference?

Comment: This is my previous command: 
gst-launch-1.0 -e --gst-plugin-path=/usr/local/lib/ aravissrc camera-name="Allied Vision-xxxxxxx-xxxxx" exposure=7000 exposure-auto=0 gain=10 gain-auto=0 ! video/x-bayer,format=rggb,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=80/1 ! bayer2rgb ! videoconvert ! vaapih264enc rate-control=cbr bitrate=5000 ! h264parse ! video/x-h264,stream-format=avc,alignment=au,profile=high ! kvssink stream-name="camera_101" storage-size=512 access-key="xxxxxxxxx" secret-key="xxxxx" aws-region="xxxxx"

Comment: It shouldn't. The encoder will always use YUV 4:2:0. If it is a difference, your CPU bottlenecks on the format conversion. Perhaps use `vapostproc` to do the colorspace conversion on the GPU too.